# Show $\int_\mathbb{R^n} e^{-||x||^2}d^n x = \pi^{n/2}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $||x||:= \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$ be the euclidean norm of a vector $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$.
Show that $$\int_\mathbb{R^n} e^{-||x||^2}d^n x = \pi^{n/2}$$

Comment: Because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$e^{-\|x\|^2} = e^{-x_1^2} \ldots e^{-x_n^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

By Fubini's Theorem, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}e^{-|x|^{2}}dx=\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}}e^{-x^{2}}dx\right)^{n}.
\end{align*}